# In iOS, how to detect from Javascript (web) the device is connected via 3G or Wifi?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad

In iOS on the web, I would like to detect from **Javascript** whether the device is connected via 3G or Wifi?

In Android, this information is available via `navigator.connection.type`. Is this information available on iOS (iPad/iPhone)?

See [How do you detect 3G vs. Wifi connection on mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8598065/813665)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. iOS does not support this natively. You have to use a framework like PhoneGap to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please share a reference for this information. Is it official by apple? What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: It was an android created property rather than W3C so Apple don't need an official reason not to support it.

Comment: Since it's standardized now ([The Network Information API](http://www.w3.org/TR/netinfo-api/#the-connection-interface)) does anyone know apple's stance?

Answer (score 0):

You can call native IOS code from javascript that looks for connectivity in Reachability API,and return back the value to Javascript..