# Determine if geolocation is supported by browser and if WiFi is on

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check in javascript if a client is using a browser capable of geolocation and has his wifi turned on (otherwise geolocation doesn't work).

How can this be done?

Comment: Geolocation does not need WiFi! The method used to obtain the position may be something else (GPS, IP-database, ...)

Comment: I believe it does, when I tested a small script it did not show my coordinates but succeeded the test to see if it was supported. After I turned my wifi on it did show my coordinates...

Comment: Your browser *may* rely on WiFi, but it doesn't *have to*.

Comment: It CAN use WiFi, but there are other methods. See the list by urzeit. GPS and WiFi are the most common for tablets and smart phones (but smart phones can also fall back to using cell phone towers). IP address and WiFi are common for laptops and desktops.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if geolocation is available with `navigator.geolocation`. But you cannot detect a wifi connection: 
[How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript)
[How do you detect 3G vs. Wifi connection on mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598065/how-do-you-detect-3g-vs-wifi-connection-on-mobile-safari)